# ActiveRecord: Result of first query ignored in multi statement query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm running a multi-statement query using ActiveRecord with Mysql(mysql2 through makara adapter) and I'm trying to store results in an array. But I don't get the result of the first query. Below is the code snippet. Please let me know what am I missing here.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    client = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection
    test_sql = "select id, email from members where id = 1; select id, pref member_prefs where member_id = 1;"
    client.query(test_sql)
    res = []
    while client.next_result
       res << client.store_result
    end

    puts "res size: #{res.size}"
    res.each do |row|
       puts "row: #{row.to_json}"
    end
end

Output:
res size: 1
row: [[1, 3]]

If I add "select 1; " before the query, it gives me two results(though the output of the 1st query is missing)
Output:
res size: 2
row: [[1, abc@def.com]]
row: [[1, 3]]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `raw_connection` returns the underlying database driver for that adapter. What database and what gem to connect to database do you use?

Comment: PG [does not handle returning multiple results from a single query](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/blob/9cf9d8aabd4a1a95ef2bc7c61054fc2cc663072b/ext/pg_connection.c#L996) and doubt the other adapters will either. What is the actual real world problem you are trying to solve and is there better solution? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @spickermann I'm using MySQL (using Makara adapter). Thanks for pointing it out. I've updated the same in question.

Comment: @max if I'm making 3 queries to DB, I should get output for all the queries, right? How I handle it afterward is a different problem to solve and I'm not worried about it right away. My expectation is simple. If I make 3 queries, I should get 3 results.

Comment: 3 queries yes, but I would not expect the driver to return multiple results for a single query containing multiple statements.

Comment: @max It's already returning multiple results. My question is why is it skipping the first result. whether I'm consuming results incorrectly or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. Probably a dumb mistake. Putting it here for reference.

The result of the first query is returned as a response of `client.query(test_sql)` statement.